# How to run PHP Mail Form Script only when someone Successfully Submit the Form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have the following code for my HTML Form with PHP on the same page. Actually, the problem is that when anybody opens the website it automatically runs the PHP `Mail()` script and send me an empty mail.

I want it to work only when somebody successfully submits the form. Please help.

```
<!--HTML FORM--><form method="post" name="contactform" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" onsubmit="return validateform()">
                <input type="text" name="fullname" class="fullname" placeholder="Full Name*"
       onfocus="this.placeholder = '';" onblur="if (this.placeholder == '') {this.placeholder = 'Full Name*';}">

                <input type="text" name="email" class="email" placeholder="Email Address*"
       onfocus="this.placeholder = '';" onblur="if (this.placeholder == '') {this.placeholder = 'Email Address*';}">

                <textarea placeholder="Your Message*:" name="message" class="message"
       onfocus="this.placeholder = '';" onblur="if (this.placeholder == '') {this.placeholder = 'Your Message*';}"></textarea>

       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form><!--/HTML FORM> <!--Contact Form PHP-->
<?php
 // define variables and set to empty values
 $fullname = $email = $message = "";
 $subject="Message from Website Visitor:".test_input($_POST["fullname"]);
 $to="camadhusudanmishra@gmail.com";
 $headers = "From:".test_input($_POST["email"]);
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 $fullname = test_input($_POST["fullname"]);
 $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
 $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);}

 function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;}
 $message = str_replace("\n.", "\n..", $message);

 mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

?>
 <!--/Contact Form PHP-->
```

JS Code for Validation:

```
    function formValidation() {
    var fullname = document.contactform.fullname;
    var email = document.contactform.email;
    var message = document.contactform.message;

    if(validateName(fullname))
    {
    if(validateEmail(email))
    {
      if(validateMessage(message))
      {
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function validateName(fullname)
  {
    var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    if(fullname.value.match(letters) && fullname.value.length >= 3 && fullname.value.length <= 30)
    {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      alert('Please enter a valid name');
      return false;
    }
  }

function validateEmail(email)
  {
    var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    if(email.value.match(mailformat))
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
      return false;
    }
  }

function validateMessage(message)
  {
    if(message.value.length >=5 && message.value.length <=300)
    {
      alert('Form Succesfully Submitted');
      window.location.reload();
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      alert("Please type a valid message.");
      return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into `if(isset( ... )){ }` and / or `if(!empty( ... )){ }` - The keywords here being `isset()` and `empty()`

Comment: Please explain why you feel the need to make the placeholder empty on focus, something the browser does for you? This code is completely redundant in my opinion `onfocus="this.placeholder = '';" onblur="if (this.placeholder == '') {this.placeholder = 'Email Address*';}"`

Comment: In ajax call , call php  page , and there itself decide  whether to send mail or not

Comment: @mplungjan This will give an effect that when someone clicks into the Form field the placeholder disappears and when someone leaves it empty, the placeholder again appears.

Comment: That is the default behaviour of the placeholder on its own. Did you try?

Comment: @mplungjan Thank You for your reply! But there is a difference between both. As I said, when someone clicks into the Form field - the placeholder disappears (with this code) where if I set it to default - the placeholder disappears when someone start writing text into the form field. (not on click).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

  // Add here function
 function test_input($data) {
 $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
 $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
 return $data;}


// define variables and set to empty values
$fullname = $email = $message = "";
$subject="Message from Website Visitor:".test_input($_POST["fullname"]);
$to="camadhusudanmishra@gmail.com";
$headers = "From:".test_input($_POST["email"]);
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$fullname = test_input($_POST["fullname"]);
$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
$message = test_input($_POST["message"]);}


 $message = str_replace("\n.", "\n..", $message);

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
 }
 ?>
  <!--/Contact Form PHP-->

 <!--HTML FORM-->
 <form method="post" name="contactform" action="<?php echo    htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" onsubmit="return validateform()">
            <input type="text" name="fullname" class="fullname" placeholder="Full Name*"
   onfocus="this.placeholder = '';" onblur="if (this.placeholder == '') {this.placeholder = 'Full Name*';}">

            <input type="text" name="email" class="email" placeholder="Email Address*"
   onfocus="this.placeholder = '';" onblur="if (this.placeholder == '') {this.placeholder = 'Email Address*';}">

            <textarea placeholder="Your Message*:" name="message" class="message"
   onfocus="this.placeholder = '';" onblur="if (this.placeholder == '') {this.placeholder = 'Your Message*';}"></textarea>

   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form><!--/HTML FORM> <!--Contact Form PHP-->
```

Comment: Thank You for Answering but it is not working. Please help.

Comment: Please tell me , your validations are working properly or not ??

Comment: Sir, they are working well but when I use your suggested PHP code - I did not receive any email when I submit the form.

Comment: Sure sir, I hope that you will definitely solve this out and help me. The whole code is hosted right now here: new.madhusudanmishra.cf if you want to check.

Comment: Just use following function    test_input($data) {
 $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
 $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
 return $data;
 }

below the following line if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

Comment: Use above code and let me know what problem comes in console

Comment: Replace your validateform function with following function     function validateform() {
    var fullname = document.contactform.fullname;
    var email = document.contactform.email;
    var message = document.contactform.message;

    if(validateName(fullname))
    {
    if(validateEmail(email))
    {
      if(validateMessage(message))
      {
       return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

Comment: Form is submitting successfully but I am not receiving any email regarding that. ok wait, sir

Comment: Awesome!! It's working sir. Many Many Thanks. Actually sir, I am a beginner developer and learning developing from different Internet websites. My core filed is totally non technical - Chartered Accountancy. Can we be friends on Facebook? www.facebook.com/danmishra